# Change the submit handler of a form of a module

Tags: 7, forms

I installed [base cart](https://www.drupal.org/project/basic_cart) module and I need to totally overwrite the submit handler of one of its forms and not to execute its default functionality at all. From what I searched, I wrote this code in `template.php` :

```
function ThemeName_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'order_node_form'){
    $form['#submit'] = 'submit';
    $form['#validate'] = '';
  }
}

function submit() {
  return "submit";
}
```

But it is not working. Is it possible to do this in `template.php` or I need to build a module to do this? or the problem is from anything else?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it solves the problem to do like this

```
$form['#submit'] = array("my_module_form_submit_handler");
```

Here's the whole function:

```
function my_theme_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#submit'] = array("my_module_form_submit_handler");
}

function my_theme_form_submit_handler($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message("The form is being submitted, do some extra stuff now...");
}
```

Comment: Can I do it in `template.php`?

Comment: Yes that is possible, just remember to clear the cache.

Comment: I guess the code `$form['#submit'][] = "my_module_form_submit_handler";` just add the new handler to the default one. Let me try it.

Comment: No, it didn't work

Comment: As I guessed it added the new function to the default ones

Comment: Are you clearing the cache?

Comment: What happens if you remove the []?

Comment: Yes, the new function appeared in `kpr($form)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76377/discussion-between-jdrupal-and-drupalist).

Comment: Still the default functions are running

Comment: @Drupalist then remove the `[]` if you don't want the default actions and use `= array("my_module_form_submit_handler");`

Comment: You could also do like this, 
$form['#submit'][0] = "my_module_form_submit_handler";

Comment: @NoSssweat, don't you think that this code could do it. $form['#submit'][0] = array("my_module_form_submit_handler");

Comment: @Jdrupal no, because if there is multiple submit handlers, then `$form['#submit'][0]`  does not override/remove `$form['#submit'][1]` .

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you got it to work :)